# How can call several times to the same class?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html, class

How can call several times to the same class?

Hello friends, I am using a famous php class for icecast2, statistics showing a mount point, could do to show me a mount point but now I want to add others to display a list of friends radios.

leave the following code in the class

```
class IceCast {

    var $server     = '';
    var $stats_file = '';
    var $radio_info = array();

    function __construct() {
        //build array to store our radio stats for later use        
        $this->radio_info['server']                = $this->server;
        $this->radio_info['title']                 = 'Offline';
        $this->radio_info['description']           = 'Radio offline';
        $this->radio_info['content_type']          = '';
        $this->radio_info['mount_start']           = '';
        $this->radio_info['bit_rate']              = '';
        $this->radio_info['listeners']             = '';
        $this->radio_info['most_listeners']        = '';
        $this->radio_info['genre']                 = '';
        $this->radio_info['url']                   = '';
        $this->radio_info['now_playing']           = array();
        $this->radio_info['now_playing']['artist'] = 'Unknown';
        $this->radio_info['now_playing']['track']  = 'Unknown';
    }

    function setUrl($url, $file) {
        $this->server               = $url;
        $this->stats_file           = $file;
        $this->radio_info['server'] = $this->server;
    }

    private function fetch() {
        //create a new curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->server . $this->stats_file);

        //return as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        //$output = our stauts.xsl file
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        //close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);

        return $output;
    }

    function getStatus() {
        $output = $this->fetch();

        //loop through $ouput and sort into our different arrays
        $temp_array = array();

        $search_for = "<td\s[^>]*class=\"streamdata\">(.*)<\/td>";
        $search_td  = array('<td class="streamdata">', '</td>');


        if (preg_match_all("/$search_for/siU", $output, $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
                $to_push = str_replace($search_td, '', $match);
                $to_push = trim($to_push);
                array_push($temp_array, $to_push);
            }
        }

        if (count($temp_array)) {
            //sort our temp array into our ral array
            $this->radio_info['title']          = $temp_array[0];
            $this->radio_info['description']    = $temp_array[1];
            $this->radio_info['content_type']   = $temp_array[2];
            $this->radio_info['mount_start']    = $temp_array[3];
            $this->radio_info['bit_rate']       = $temp_array[4];
            $this->radio_info['listeners']      = $temp_array[5];
            $this->radio_info['most_listeners'] = $temp_array[6];
            $this->radio_info['genre']          = $temp_array[7];
            $this->radio_info['url']            = $temp_array[8];

            if (isset($temp_array[9])) {
                $x                                         = explode(" - ", $temp_array[9]);
                $this->radio_info['now_playing']['artist'] = $x[0];
                $this->radio_info['now_playing']['track']  = $x[1];
            }
        }
        return $this->radio_info;
    }

}
```

and this is my script currently works well, now I want to see how to add other mountpoint and show your divs below

```
<?php

//class
require_once('icecast.php');
$oIceCast = new IceCast();

//change var my radio
$server = 'http://giss.tv:8000';
$file   = '/status.xsl?mount=/radio.mp3';

$oIceCast->setUrl($server, $file);
$status = $oIceCast->getStatus();
$result .= <<<EOF
    <div><strong>Name</strong> {$status['title']}</div>
    <div><strong>Description</strong> {$status['description']}</div>
    <audio controls>
    <source src="http://giss.tv:8000/radio.mp3">
    <!-- This is Where You Enter Your Flash Fall Back -->
    </audio>
    <div><strong>Start</strong> {$status['mount_start']}</div>
    <div><strong>Listeners</strong> {$status['listeners']}</div>
    <div><strong>Max listeners</strong> {$status['most_listeners']}</div>
    <div><strong>Url</strong> {$status['url']}</div>
    <div><strong>Artist</strong> {$status['now_playing']['artist']}</div>
    <div><strong>Track</strong> {$status['now_playing']['track']}</div>
    EOF;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <?= $result ?>
      </div><!--/.container-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope you can help me or guide
thanks

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, can you please be more explanatory?

Comment: you mean like instantiating two object? for example `$oIceCast2 = new IceCast();`

Comment: Yes, I need something similar but not as it is called or made
using the same class, bring other objects about 15 more, so show me the status of 15 radios more, thank you very much